# tem como obter o valor numerico de uma tag sem ser por id, no caso uma class e depois dividir por outro número e mostrar dentro do site

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer uma extensão para o chrome, a ideia é pegar um valor numerico de dentro de um site, em sua página e fazer contar somando, subtraindo, dividindo e etc e então mostrar o resultado ao lado do valor como uma calculadorinha eu tentei algumas coisas e consegui por Id, mas quando na tag é uma class não estou conseguindo:

aqui o manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "name": "test calc",
    "description": "calc",
    "author": "LA",
    "browser_action": {
     "default_title": "Alterando valor",
     "default_popup": "index.html",
     "default_icon": "icon.png"

 },
 "content_scripts":[
 {
 "js": [ 
 "captura.js"
 ],
 "matches": [
 
 "https://sitequalquer/*"
 ]
 
 }
 
 ]
   
}
```

e aqui o javascript

```
var url = document.getElementById('Idtal').text;
alert(url);

var url = document.getElementsByClassName('classetal').innerText;
alert(url);

var url_ = document.getElementsByClassName('classetal')[0].innerHTML;
alert(url_);

var url_ = document.getElementsByClassName('classetal')[0].value + ",";
alert(url_);
```

outra duvida é: depois eu preciso usar um operador com as var e enviar por alert, correto?

Answer (score 0):

O `getElementsByClassName` retorna um array e o objeto que contem seu texto é o `textContent`, [veja este exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/1bryns23/1/).

```
var url = document.getElementById('this-id').textContent
alert(url);

var url = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[0].textContent
alert(url);
```

Quanto sua outra duvida: você pode fazer isso:

```
var a = 5;
alert(a + 45); //output: 50
```

Comment: nossa, muito obrigada Felipe Chagas
funcionou direitinho
era isso mesmo
obrigada mesmo =D

Comment: De nada! Se matou a duvida, pode marcar como solução, para fechar a questão, por favor.